# Set addition confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose

$U=\{(x,x,y,y) \in\mathbf{F}^4\mid x,y \in\mathbf{F}\}$

$W=\{(x,x,x,y) \in\mathbf{F}^4\mid x,y \in\mathbf{F}\}$

where $\mathbf{F}$ is $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$

$U+W=\{(x,x,y,z) \in\mathbf{F}^4\mid x,y,z \in\mathbf{F}\}$

I think I am having a hard time understanding the definition of subset additions, I got something like $\{(x+x),(x+x),(x+y),(y+y)\}$. I'm not quite sure what I am doing.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading your question--please see the [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on typesetting your questions correctly.

Comment: is this better?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the same variables when adding.

$U = \{ (x_1,x_1,y_1,y_1) | x_1,y_1 \in F \}$.

$W = \{ (x_2,x_2,x_2,y_2) | x_2,y_2 \in F \}$.

Then $U+W = \{ (x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2, y_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)| x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 \in F\}$.

Without knowing more about $F$ this is as simple as the description will get.

If $F$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ we can simplify a little more.

We can write  $L=\{ (x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2, y_1+x_2, y_1+y_2)| x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2 \in F\} = R=\{ (z_1, z_1, z_2, z_3)| z_1,z_2,z_3 \in F\}$.

To see this pick a point $(x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2, y_1+x_2, y_1+y_2) \in L$. Let
$z_1 = x_1+x_2$, $z_2 = y_1+x_2$, and $z_3= y_1+y_2$, then $(z_1,z_1,z_2,z_3) \in R$, so we see that $L \subset R$. Now pick a point $(z_1,z_1,z_2,z_3) \in R$. Let $y_2 = 0$, $y_1 = z_3$, $x_2 = z_2-z_3$, and $x_1= z_1-z_2+z_3$, then
$(z_1,z_1,z_2,z_3)=(x_1+x_2, x_1+x_2, y_1+x_2, y_1+y_2) \in L$ and so
$R \subset L$.

Comment: I copied this directly from the book, my first thought was what you mentioned to use different variables, but where did the z come from?

Comment: What $z$? ${}{}$

Comment: I misunderstood something, I think. Is $F$ equal to the set of all reals or all complex numbers?

Comment: yes F is the set of all reals and all complex numbers

Comment: Hopefully the addition clarifies the situation a little.